# Problems while drawing on an HDC that was attached to CDC

Tags: c++, mfc, drawing, gdi

I've a working application that has some custom drawn controls, This application was based on the OWL library, I'm moving It to MFC alot of work has been done but the custom drawing is a real problem, The application used the **TDC** that is alternative to MFC **CDC** I created class caled TDC that inherits from the CDC and I provided it with the required methods.

The TDC works like the following

```
HDC hdc = GetDC();
TDC dc(hdc);//in this constructor I call the CDC::Attach method to attach the hdc
//start drawing....
```

this cause a problem in drawing just defining a TDC that take an hdc then drawing on this hdc will not be successful when I draw directly to the native hdc without attaching it works fine.

```
HDC hdc = GetDC();
//TDC dc(hdc);//when this line is commented everything is fine but if it is uncommented this will lead to problems
GdiPlus::Graphics gx(hdc);
//start drawing....
```

those images to describe what are the problems befor the conversion and after the conversion, the one on the left is after I make TDC inherits from the MFC CDC, the one on the right is the well working one that was built on the OWL

[image: Bad Drawing after migration to MFC]

What can cause this? I just attached the hdc to the CDC parent of TDC! this is really strange.

also when the mouse move over a menu item it is drawn focused correct.

Comment: You should provide a little more code. Your example do not show the lifetime cycle of your TDC object. Do you detach the hDC before destroying it? Please provide constructor/destructor and the draw routine (shorten down to the bug).

Comment: When you Attach to the CDC, what do you do upon destruction? Hopefully you detach the DC again, otherwise the destructor will do "bad things"... I don't think that it is wise to introduce a new TDC class, because CDC is a base class for CWindowDC and others... Why do you need your own class?

Comment: @MartinSchlott: the TDC is just inheriting from the CDC attach it on the constructor and do nothing at destruction because I thought the CDC destructor will do this, should I detach it? and if yes, why if the CDC will detach it.

Comment: @xMRi: as i said to Martin Schlott I did nothing in the destructor, see the previous comment, for your asking about having a new class TDC , The answer is that I'm converting a code that is so messy and so big its being developed and growing since about 1994,it has millions of lines a large thing that i can't move iside it and rewrite its grapghics or its GUI classes, My mission is to convert from the OWL to MFC without touching any logic, They depended on TDC class of OWL I removed the OWL , to solve this dependency I provided new TDC as an interface between the software and the CDC.

Comment: @xMRi: the TDC has little methods than those of CDC but the signature is different for example TRect instead of CRect, TPoint instead of CPoint, and passing by refernce or by pointer.... to comeover this I provided my new class TDC with the methods that the software expect them and inside them I called the alternative in the CDC.

Comment: @Ahmed safan It's been a while when I last programmed MFC. Both CDC and Graphics should leave the HDC untouched. But for testing, you should detach it from your TDC before it is going out of scope. If it resolves the issue, your problem is by the destruction of TDC.

Comment: What Martin Schlott wrote is what I mentioned before. Detach before your helper class gets out of scope!